# What prescaler to use for finer control?

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

I'm using a UNO to generate a 10 kHz PWM signal. I need finer duty cycle variation.
The prescalers supported are 1, 8, 32, and 64.

```cpp
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  TCCR2A = bit (WGM20) | bit (WGM21) | bit (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2A on compare
  TCCR2B = bit (WGM22) | bit (CS22); // fast PWM, prescaler of 64
  OCR2A = 63; // prescaler 32 with 10Khz
  OCR2B = ((64 + 1)/2) - 1; // 50% duty cycle
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is perfectly valid.

Comment: From the layout and the comments, this code is clearly from [my page about timers](http://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11504&reply=8#reply8) which is gratifying, that it is useful to people.

Answer (score 1):

The lower prescalers will give you finer control. The bigger prescalers necessarily have coarser control.

From [my web page about timers](http://gammon.com.au/timers) is this table of prescalers:

```
  n  -- Prescale 1   --  -- Prescale 8   --  -- Prescale 64  --  -- Prescale 256 --  -- Prescale 1024--
     Freq (Hz) Per (µs)  Freq (Hz) Per (µs)  Freq (Hz) Per (µs)  Freq (Hz) Per (µs)  Freq (Hz) Per (µs)
  1: 8,000,000*   0.125  1,000,000    1.000    125,000    8.000     31,250   32.000      7,813  128.000  
  2: 5,333,333    0.188    666,667    1.500     83,333   12.000     20,833   48.000      5,208  192.000  
  3: 4,000,000    0.250    500,000    2.000     62,500   16.000     15,625   64.000      3,906  256.000  
  4: 3,200,000    0.313    400,000    2.500     50,000   20.000     12,500   80.000      3,125  320.000  
  5: 2,666,667    0.375    333,333    3.000     41,667   24.000     10,417   96.000      2,604  384.000  
  6: 2,285,714    0.438    285,714    3.500     35,714   28.000      8,929  112.000      2,232  448.000  
  7: 2,000,000    0.500    250,000    4.000     31,250   32.000      7,813  128.000      1,953  512.000  
  8: 1,777,778    0.563    222,222    4.500     27,778   36.000      6,944  144.000      1,736  576.000  
  9: 1,600,000    0.625    200,000    5.000     25,000   40.000      6,250  160.000      1,563  640.000  
 10: 1,454,545    0.688    181,818    5.500     22,727   44.000      5,682  176.000      1,420  704.000  
 11: 1,333,333    0.750    166,667    6.000     20,833   48.000      5,208  192.000      1,302  768.000  
 12: 1,230,769    0.813    153,846    6.500     19,231   52.000      4,808  208.000      1,202  832.000  
 13: 1,142,857    0.875    142,857    7.000     17,857   56.000      4,464  224.000      1,116  896.000  
 14: 1,066,667    0.937    133,333    7.500     16,667   60.000      4,167  240.000      1,042  960.000  
 15: 1,000,000    1.000    125,000    8.000     15,625   64.000      3,906  256.000        977 1024.000  
 16:   941,176    1.063    117,647    8.500     14,706   68.000      3,676  272.000        919 1088.000  
 17:   888,889    1.125    111,111    9.000     13,889   72.000      3,472  288.000        868 1152.000  
 18:   842,105    1.187    105,263    9.500     13,158   76.000      3,289  304.000        822 1216.000  
 19:   800,000    1.250    100,000   10.000     12,500   80.000      3,125  320.000        781 1280.000  
 20:   761,905    1.313     95,238   10.500     11,905   84.000      2,976  336.000        744 1344.000  
 21:   727,273    1.375     90,909   11.000     11,364   88.000      2,841  352.000        710 1408.000  
 22:   695,652    1.438     86,957   11.500     10,870   92.000      2,717  368.000        679 1472.000  
 23:   666,667    1.500     83,333   12.000     10,417   96.000      2,604  384.000        651 1536.000  
 24:   640,000    1.562     80,000   12.500     10,000  100.000      2,500  400.000        625 1600.000  
 25:   615,385    1.625     76,923   13.000      9,615  104.000      2,404  416.000        601 1664.000  
 26:   592,593    1.688     74,074   13.500      9,259  108.000      2,315  432.000        579 1728.000  
 27:   571,429    1.750     71,429   14.000      8,929  112.000      2,232  448.000        558 1792.000  
 28:   551,724    1.813     68,966   14.500      8,621  116.000      2,155  464.000        539 1856.000  
 29:   533,333    1.875     66,667   15.000      8,333  120.000      2,083  480.000        521 1920.000  
 30:   516,129    1.938     64,516   15.500      8,065  124.000      2,016  496.000        504 1984.000  
 31:   500,000    2.000     62,500   16.000      7,813  128.000      1,953  512.000        488 2048.000  
 32:   484,848    2.062     60,606   16.500      7,576  132.000      1,894  528.000        473 2112.000  
 33:   470,588    2.125     58,824   17.000      7,353  136.000      1,838  544.000        460 2176.000  
 34:   457,143    2.188     57,143   17.500      7,143  140.000      1,786  560.000        446 2240.000  
 35:   444,444    2.250     55,556   18.000      6,944  144.000      1,736  576.000        434 2304.000  
 36:   432,432    2.313     54,054   18.500      6,757  148.000      1,689  592.000        422 2368.000  
 37:   421,053    2.375     52,632   19.000      6,579  152.000      1,645  608.000        411 2432.000  
 38:   410,256    2.438     51,282   19.500      6,410  156.000      1,603  624.000        401 2496.000  
 39:   400,000    2.500     50,000   20.000      6,250  160.000      1,563  640.000        391 2560.000  
 40:   390,244    2.563     48,780   20.500      6,098  164.000      1,524  656.000        381 2624.000  
 41:   380,952    2.625     47,619   21.000      5,952  168.000      1,488  672.000        372 2688.000  
 42:   372,093    2.687     46,512   21.500      5,814  172.000      1,453  688.000        363 2752.000  
 43:   363,636    2.750     45,455   22.000      5,682  176.000      1,420  704.000        355 2816.000  
 44:   355,556    2.812     44,444   22.500      5,556  180.000      1,389  720.000        347 2880.000  
 45:   347,826    2.875     43,478   23.000      5,435  184.000      1,359  736.000        340 2944.000  
 46:   340,426    2.938     42,553   23.500      5,319  188.000      1,330  752.000        332 3008.000  
 47:   333,333    3.000     41,667   24.000      5,208  192.000      1,302  768.000        326 3072.000  
 48:   326,531    3.063     40,816   24.500      5,102  196.000      1,276  784.000        319 3136.000  
 49:   320,000    3.125     40,000   25.000      5,000  200.000      1,250  800.000        313 3200.000  
 50:   313,725    3.188     39,216   25.500      4,902  204.000      1,225  816.000        306 3264.000  
 51:   307,692    3.250     38,462   26.000      4,808  208.000      1,202  832.000        300 3328.000  
 52:   301,887    3.313     37,736   26.500      4,717  212.000      1,179  848.000        295 3392.000  
 53:   296,296    3.375     37,037   27.000      4,630  216.000      1,157  864.000        289 3456.000  
 54:   290,909    3.437     36,364   27.500      4,545  220.000      1,136  880.000        284 3520.000  
 55:   285,714    3.500     35,714   28.000      4,464  224.000      1,116  896.000        279 3584.000  
 56:   280,702    3.562     35,088   28.500      4,386  228.000      1,096  912.000        274 3648.000  
 57:   275,862    3.625     34,483   29.000      4,310  232.000      1,078  928.000        269 3712.000  
 58:   271,186    3.688     33,898   29.500      4,237  236.000      1,059  944.000        265 3776.000  
 59:   266,667    3.750     33,333   30.000      4,167  240.000      1,042  960.000        260 3840.000  
 60:   262,295    3.813     32,787   30.500      4,098  244.000      1,025  976.000        256 3904.000  
 61:   258,065    3.875     32,258   31.000      4,032  248.000      1,008  992.000        252 3968.000  
 62:   253,968    3.938     31,746   31.500      3,968  252.000        992 1008.000        248 4032.000  
 63:   250,000    4.000     31,250   32.000      3,906  256.000        977 1024.000        244 4096.000  
 64:   246,154    4.063     30,769   32.500      3,846  260.000        962 1040.000        240 4160.000  
 65:   242,424    4.125     30,303   33.000      3,788  264.000        947 1056.000        237 4224.000  
 66:   238,806    4.188     29,851   33.500      3,731  268.000        933 1072.000        233 4288.000  
 67:   235,294    4.250     29,412   34.000      3,676  272.000        919 1088.000        230 4352.000  
 68:   231,884    4.313     28,986   34.500      3,623  276.000        906 1104.000        226 4416.000  
 69:   228,571    4.375     28,571   35.000      3,571  280.000        893 1120.000        223 4480.000  
 70:   225,352    4.437     28,169   35.500      3,521  284.000        880 1136.000        220 4544.000  
 71:   222,222    4.500     27,778   36.000      3,472  288.000        868 1152.000        217 4608.000  
 72:   219,178    4.563     27,397   36.500      3,425  292.000        856 1168.000        214 4672.000  
 73:   216,216    4.625     27,027   37.000      3,378  296.000        845 1184.000        211 4736.000  
 74:   213,333    4.688     26,667   37.500      3,333  300.000        833 1200.000        208 4800.000  
 75:   210,526    4.750     26,316   38.000      3,289  304.000        822 1216.000        206 4864.000  
 76:   207,792    4.813     25,974   38.500      3,247  308.000        812 1232.000        203 4928.000  
 77:   205,128    4.875     25,641   39.000      3,205  312.000        801 1248.000        200 4992.000  
 78:   202,532    4.938     25,316   39.500      3,165  316.000        791 1264.000        198 5056.000  
 79:   200,000    5.000     25,000   40.000      3,125  320.000        781 1280.000        195 5120.000  
 80:   197,531    5.062     24,691   40.500      3,086  324.000        772 1296.000        193 5184.000  
 81:   195,122    5.125     24,390   41.000      3,049  328.000        762 1312.000        191 5248.000  
 82:   192,771    5.188     24,096   41.500      3,012  332.000        753 1328.000        188 5312.000  
 83:   190,476    5.250     23,810   42.000      2,976  336.000        744 1344.000        186 5376.000  
 84:   188,235    5.312     23,529   42.500      2,941  340.000        735 1360.000        184 5440.000  
 85:   186,047    5.375     23,256   43.000      2,907  344.000        727 1376.000        182 5504.000  
 86:   183,908    5.438     22,989   43.500      2,874  348.000        718 1392.000        180 5568.000  
 87:   181,818    5.500     22,727   44.000      2,841  352.000        710 1408.000        178 5632.000  
 88:   179,775    5.563     22,472   44.500      2,809  356.000        702 1424.000        176 5696.000  
 89:   177,778    5.625     22,222   45.000      2,778  360.000        694 1440.000        174 5760.000  
 90:   175,824    5.687     21,978   45.500      2,747  364.000        687 1456.000        172 5824.000  
 91:   173,913    5.750     21,739   46.000      2,717  368.000        679 1472.000        170 5888.000  
 92:   172,043    5.813     21,505   46.500      2,688  372.000        672 1488.000        168 5952.000  
 93:   170,213    5.875     21,277   47.000      2,660  376.000        665 1504.000        166 6016.000  
 94:   168,421    5.937     21,053   47.500      2,632  380.000        658 1520.000        164 6080.000  
 95:   166,667    6.000     20,833   48.000      2,604  384.000        651 1536.000        163 6144.000  
 96:   164,948    6.063     20,619   48.500      2,577  388.000        644 1552.000        161 6208.000  
 97:   163,265    6.125     20,408   49.000      2,551  392.000        638 1568.000        159 6272.000  
 98:   161,616    6.188     20,202   49.500      2,525  396.000        631 1584.000        158 6336.000  
 99:   160,000    6.250     20,000   50.000      2,500  400.000        625 1600.000        156 6400.000  
100:   158,416    6.313     19,802   50.500      2,475  404.000        619 1616.000        155 6464.000  
101:   156,863    6.375     19,608   51.000      2,451  408.000        613 1632.000        153 6528.000  
102:   155,340    6.438     19,417   51.500      2,427  412.000        607 1648.000        152 6592.000  
103:   153,846    6.500     19,231   52.000      2,404  416.000        601 1664.000        150 6656.000  
104:   152,381    6.562     19,048   52.500      2,381  420.000        595 1680.000        149 6720.000  
105:   150,943    6.625     18,868   53.000      2,358  424.000        590 1696.000        147 6784.000  
106:   149,533    6.688     18,692   53.500      2,336  428.000        584 1712.000        146 6848.000  
107:   148,148    6.750     18,519   54.000      2,315  432.000        579 1728.000        145 6912.000  
108:   146,789    6.813     18,349   54.500      2,294  436.000        573 1744.000        143 6976.000  
109:   145,455    6.875     18,182   55.000      2,273  440.000        568 1760.000        142 7040.000  
110:   144,144    6.938     18,018   55.500      2,252  444.000        563 1776.000        141 7104.000  
111:   142,857    7.000     17,857   56.000      2,232  448.000        558 1792.000        140 7168.000  
112:   141,593    7.063     17,699   56.500      2,212  452.000        553 1808.000        138 7232.000  
113:   140,351    7.125     17,544   57.000      2,193  456.000        548 1824.000        137 7296.000  
114:   139,130    7.187     17,391   57.500      2,174  460.000        543 1840.000        136 7360.000  
115:   137,931    7.250     17,241   58.000      2,155  464.000        539 1856.000        135 7424.000  
116:   136,752    7.313     17,094   58.500      2,137  468.000        534 1872.000        134 7488.000  
117:   135,593    7.375     16,949   59.000      2,119  472.000        530 1888.000        132 7552.000  
118:   134,454    7.437     16,807   59.500      2,101  476.000        525 1904.000        131 7616.000  
119:   133,333    7.500     16,667   60.000      2,083  480.000        521 1920.000        130 7680.000  
120:   132,231    7.563     16,529   60.500      2,066  484.000        517 1936.000        129 7744.000  
121:   131,148    7.625     16,393   61.000      2,049  488.000        512 1952.000        128 7808.000  
122:   130,081    7.687     16,260   61.500      2,033  492.000        508 1968.000        127 7872.000  
123:   129,032    7.750     16,129   62.000      2,016  496.000        504 1984.000        126 7936.000  
124:   128,000    7.813     16,000   62.500      2,000  500.000        500 2000.000        125 8000.000  
125:   126,984    7.875     15,873   63.000      1,984  504.000        496 2016.000        124 8064.000  
126:   125,984    7.938     15,748   63.500      1,969  508.000        492 2032.000        123 8128.000  
127:   125,000    8.000     15,625   64.000      1,953  512.000        488 2048.000        122 8192.000  
128:   124,031    8.063     15,504   64.500      1,938  516.000        484 2064.000        121 8256.000  
129:   123,077    8.125     15,385   65.000      1,923  520.000        481 2080.000        120 8320.000  
130:   122,137    8.188     15,267   65.500      1,908  524.000        477 2096.000        119 8384.000  
131:   121,212    8.250     15,152   66.000      1,894  528.000        473 2112.000        118 8448.000  
132:   120,301    8.313     15,038   66.500      1,880  532.000        470 2128.000        117 8512.000  
133:   119,403    8.375     14,925   67.000      1,866  536.000        466 2144.000        117 8576.000  
134:   118,519    8.438     14,815   67.500      1,852  540.000        463 2160.000        116 8640.000  
135:   117,647    8.500     14,706   68.000      1,838  544.000        460 2176.000        115 8704.000  
136:   116,788    8.563     14,599   68.500      1,825  548.000        456 2192.000        114 8768.000  
137:   115,942    8.625     14,493   69.000      1,812  552.000        453 2208.000        113 8832.000  
138:   115,108    8.688     14,388   69.500      1,799  556.000        450 2224.000        112 8896.000  
139:   114,286    8.750     14,286   70.000      1,786  560.000        446 2240.000        112 8960.000  
140:   113,475    8.812     14,184   70.500      1,773  564.000        443 2256.000        111 9024.000  
141:   112,676    8.875     14,085   71.000      1,761  568.000        440 2272.000        110 9088.000  
142:   111,888    8.938     13,986   71.500      1,748  572.000        437 2288.000        109 9152.000  
143:   111,111    9.000     13,889   72.000      1,736  576.000        434 2304.000        109 9216.000  
144:   110,345    9.063     13,793   72.500      1,724  580.000        431 2320.000        108 9280.000  
145:   109,589    9.125     13,699   73.000      1,712  584.000        428 2336.000        107 9344.000  
146:   108,844    9.188     13,605   73.500      1,701  588.000        425 2352.000        106 9408.000  
147:   108,108    9.250     13,514   74.000      1,689  592.000        422 2368.000        106 9472.000  
148:   107,383    9.313     13,423   74.500      1,678  596.000        419 2384.000        105 9536.000  
149:   106,667    9.375     13,333   75.000      1,667  600.000        417 2400.000        104 9600.000  
150:   105,960    9.437     13,245   75.500      1,656  604.000        414 2416.000        103 9664.000  
151:   105,263    9.500     13,158   76.000      1,645  608.000        411 2432.000        103 9728.000  
152:   104,575    9.563     13,072   76.500      1,634  612.000        408 2448.000        102 9792.000  
153:   103,896    9.625     12,987   77.000      1,623  616.000        406 2464.000        101 9856.000  
154:   103,226    9.688     12,903   77.500      1,613  620.000        403 2480.000        101 9920.000  
155:   102,564    9.750     12,821   78.000      1,603  624.000        401 2496.000        100 9984.000  
156:   101,911    9.813     12,739   78.500      1,592  628.000        398 2512.000        100 10048.000  
157:   101,266    9.875     12,658   79.000      1,582  632.000        396 2528.000         99 10112.000  
158:   100,629    9.938     12,579   79.500      1,572  636.000        393 2544.000         98 10176.000  
159:   100,000   10.000     12,500   80.000      1,563  640.000        391 2560.000         98 10240.000  
160:    99,379   10.062     12,422   80.500      1,553  644.000        388 2576.000         97 10304.000  
161:    98,765   10.125     12,346   81.000      1,543  648.000        386 2592.000         96 10368.000  
162:    98,160   10.188     12,270   81.500      1,534  652.000        383 2608.000         96 10432.000  
163:    97,561   10.250     12,195   82.000      1,524  656.000        381 2624.000         95 10496.000  
164:    96,970   10.313     12,121   82.500      1,515  660.000        379 2640.000         95 10560.000  
165:    96,386   10.375     12,048   83.000      1,506  664.000        377 2656.000         94 10624.000  
166:    95,808   10.438     11,976   83.500      1,497  668.000        374 2672.000         94 10688.000  
167:    95,238   10.500     11,905   84.000      1,488  672.000        372 2688.000         93 10752.000  
168:    94,675   10.563     11,834   84.500      1,479  676.000        370 2704.000         92 10816.000  
169:    94,118   10.625     11,765   85.000      1,471  680.000        368 2720.000         92 10880.000  
170:    93,567   10.687     11,696   85.500      1,462  684.000        365 2736.000         91 10944.000  
171:    93,023   10.750     11,628   86.000      1,453  688.000        363 2752.000         91 11008.000  
172:    92,486   10.813     11,561   86.500      1,445  692.000        361 2768.000         90 11072.000  
173:    91,954   10.875     11,494   87.000      1,437  696.000        359 2784.000         90 11136.000  
174:    91,429   10.938     11,429   87.500      1,429  700.000        357 2800.000         89 11200.000  
175:    90,909   11.000     11,364   88.000      1,420  704.000        355 2816.000         89 11264.000  
176:    90,395   11.063     11,299   88.500      1,412  708.000        353 2832.000         88 11328.000  
177:    89,888   11.125     11,236   89.000      1,404  712.000        351 2848.000         88 11392.000  
178:    89,385   11.188     11,173   89.500      1,397  716.000        349 2864.000         87 11456.000  
179:    88,889   11.250     11,111   90.000      1,389  720.000        347 2880.000         87 11520.000  
180:    88,398   11.312     11,050   90.500      1,381  724.000        345 2896.000         86 11584.000  
181:    87,912   11.375     10,989   91.000      1,374  728.000        343 2912.000         86 11648.000  
182:    87,432   11.438     10,929   91.500      1,366  732.000        342 2928.000         85 11712.000  
183:    86,957   11.500     10,870   92.000      1,359  736.000        340 2944.000         85 11776.000  
184:    86,486   11.563     10,811   92.500      1,351  740.000        338 2960.000         84 11840.000  
185:    86,022   11.625     10,753   93.000      1,344  744.000        336 2976.000         84 11904.000  
186:    85,561   11.688     10,695   93.500      1,337  748.000        334 2992.000         84 11968.000  
187:    85,106   11.750     10,638   94.000      1,330  752.000        332 3008.000         83 12032.000  
188:    84,656   11.813     10,582   94.500      1,323  756.000        331 3024.000         83 12096.000  
189:    84,211   11.875     10,526   95.000      1,316  760.000        329 3040.000         82 12160.000  
190:    83,770   11.937     10,471   95.500      1,309  764.000        327 3056.000         82 12224.000  
191:    83,333   12.000     10,417   96.000      1,302  768.000        326 3072.000         81 12288.000  
192:    82,902   12.063     10,363   96.500      1,295  772.000        324 3088.000         81 12352.000  
193:    82,474   12.125     10,309   97.000      1,289  776.000        322 3104.000         81 12416.000  
194:    82,051   12.188     10,256   97.500      1,282  780.000        321 3120.000         80 12480.000  
195:    81,633   12.250     10,204   98.000      1,276  784.000        319 3136.000         80 12544.000  
196:    81,218   12.313     10,152   98.500      1,269  788.000        317 3152.000         79 12608.000  
197:    80,808   12.375     10,101   99.000      1,263  792.000        316 3168.000         79 12672.000  
198:    80,402   12.437     10,050   99.500      1,256  796.000        314 3184.000         79 12736.000  
199:    80,000   12.500     10,000  100.000      1,250  800.000        313 3200.000         78 12800.000  
200:    79,602   12.562      9,950  100.500      1,244  804.000        311 3216.000         78 12864.000  
201:    79,208   12.625      9,901  101.000      1,238  808.000        309 3232.000         77 12928.000  
202:    78,818   12.688      9,852  101.500      1,232  812.000        308 3248.000         77 12992.000  
203:    78,431   12.750      9,804  102.000      1,225  816.000        306 3264.000         77 13056.000  
204:    78,049   12.813      9,756  102.500      1,220  820.000        305 3280.000         76 13120.000  
205:    77,670   12.875      9,709  103.000      1,214  824.000        303 3296.000         76 13184.000  
206:    77,295   12.938      9,662  103.500      1,208  828.000        302 3312.000         75 13248.000  
207:    76,923   13.000      9,615  104.000      1,202  832.000        300 3328.000         75 13312.000  
208:    76,555   13.062      9,569  104.500      1,196  836.000        299 3344.000         75 13376.000  
209:    76,190   13.125      9,524  105.000      1,190  840.000        298 3360.000         74 13440.000  
210:    75,829   13.187      9,479  105.500      1,185  844.000        296 3376.000         74 13504.000  
211:    75,472   13.250      9,434  106.000      1,179  848.000        295 3392.000         74 13568.000  
212:    75,117   13.313      9,390  106.500      1,174  852.000        293 3408.000         73 13632.000  
213:    74,766   13.375      9,346  107.000      1,168  856.000        292 3424.000         73 13696.000  
214:    74,419   13.438      9,302  107.500      1,163  860.000        291 3440.000         73 13760.000  
215:    74,074   13.500      9,259  108.000      1,157  864.000        289 3456.000         72 13824.000  
216:    73,733   13.563      9,217  108.500      1,152  868.000        288 3472.000         72 13888.000  
217:    73,394   13.625      9,174  109.000      1,147  872.000        287 3488.000         72 13952.000  
218:    73,059   13.687      9,132  109.500      1,142  876.000        285 3504.000         71 14016.000  
219:    72,727   13.750      9,091  110.000      1,136  880.000        284 3520.000         71 14080.000  
220:    72,398   13.812      9,050  110.500      1,131  884.000        283 3536.000         71 14144.000  
221:    72,072   13.875      9,009  111.000      1,126  888.000        282 3552.000         70 14208.000  
222:    71,749   13.938      8,969  111.500      1,121  892.000        280 3568.000         70 14272.000  
223:    71,429   14.000      8,929  112.000      1,116  896.000        279 3584.000         70 14336.000  
224:    71,111   14.063      8,889  112.500      1,111  900.000        278 3600.000         69 14400.000  
225:    70,796   14.125      8,850  113.000      1,106  904.000        277 3616.000         69 14464.000  
226:    70,485   14.188      8,811  113.500      1,101  908.000        275 3632.000         69 14528.000  
227:    70,175   14.250      8,772  114.000      1,096  912.000        274 3648.000         69 14592.000  
228:    69,869   14.312      8,734  114.500      1,092  916.000        273 3664.000         68 14656.000  
229:    69,565   14.375      8,696  115.000      1,087  920.000        272 3680.000         68 14720.000  
230:    69,264   14.437      8,658  115.500      1,082  924.000        271 3696.000         68 14784.000  
231:    68,966   14.500      8,621  116.000      1,078  928.000        269 3712.000         67 14848.000  
232:    68,670   14.563      8,584  116.500      1,073  932.000        268 3728.000         67 14912.000  
233:    68,376   14.625      8,547  117.000      1,068  936.000        267 3744.000         67 14976.000  
234:    68,085   14.688      8,511  117.500      1,064  940.000        266 3760.000         66 15040.000  
235:    67,797   14.750      8,475  118.000      1,059  944.000        265 3776.000         66 15104.000  
236:    67,511   14.813      8,439  118.500      1,055  948.000        264 3792.000         66 15168.000  
237:    67,227   14.875      8,403  119.000      1,050  952.000        263 3808.000         66 15232.000  
238:    66,946   14.937      8,368  119.500      1,046  956.000        262 3824.000         65 15296.000  
239:    66,667   15.000      8,333  120.000      1,042  960.000        260 3840.000         65 15360.000  
240:    66,390   15.062      8,299  120.500      1,037  964.000        259 3856.000         65 15424.000  
241:    66,116   15.125      8,264  121.000      1,033  968.000        258 3872.000         65 15488.000  
242:    65,844   15.188      8,230  121.500      1,029  972.000        257 3888.000         64 15552.000  
243:    65,574   15.250      8,197  122.000      1,025  976.000        256 3904.000         64 15616.000  
244:    65,306   15.313      8,163  122.500      1,020  980.000        255 3920.000         64 15680.000  
245:    65,041   15.375      8,130  123.000      1,016  984.000        254 3936.000         64 15744.000  
246:    64,777   15.438      8,097  123.500      1,012  988.000        253 3952.000         63 15808.000  
247:    64,516   15.500      8,065  124.000      1,008  992.000        252 3968.000         63 15872.000  
248:    64,257   15.562      8,032  124.500      1,004  996.000        251 3984.000         63 15936.000  
249:    64,000   15.625      8,000  125.000      1,000 1000.000        250 4000.000         63 16000.000  
250:    63,745   15.687      7,968  125.500        996 1004.000        249 4016.000         62 16064.000  
251:    63,492   15.750      7,937  126.000        992 1008.000        248 4032.000         62 16128.000  
252:    63,241   15.812      7,905  126.500        988 1012.000        247 4048.000         62 16192.000  
253:    62,992   15.875      7,874  127.000        984 1016.000        246 4064.000         62 16256.000  
254:    62,745   15.937      7,843  127.500        980 1020.000        245 4080.000         61 16320.000  
255:    62,500   16.000      7,813  128.000        977 1024.000        244 4096.000         61 16384.000
```

A prescaler of one, being the finest, will not be adequate because you cannot get a frequency of 10 kHz (from the above table). In other words, dividing the Uno clock of 16 MHz by 256 only gives you a frequency of 62500 Hz (16000000 / 256).

Using a prescaler of 8 and a counter of 199 gives you 10 kHz: 16000000 / 8 / 200 = 10000. I say a counter of 199, and not 200, because the  counters are zero-relative.

This is the finest prescaler, and thus would give you the finest duty cycle control. You still only have 256 steps of duty cycle because this is an 8-bit timer. For finer control use Timer 1, which is a 16-bit timer.